# EF Core/LINQ - Best solution between Select() and Async Eager Loading?

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, entity-framework-core

I wanted to use a `Select()` method but it seems like `Select()` doesn't really accept the await keyword. Therefore I was asking myself the question, should I keep using Eager Loading asynchronously or actually the Select method is very good synchronously and will do the job as efficiently as the other ?

I use the `Select()` to map a very large entity to a DTO and Eager Loading to basically mimic the `Select()` method by creating a bunch of method including a few relationships such as `GetObjectWithPrice` and `GetObjectWithPriceAndDate` and so that's why I was asking for the use of a `Select()` method instead but the **synchronicity** worries me.

EDIT

To answer @AvrohomYisroel, here's what I've been doing with my code so far:

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyList<Book>> GetAllBooksWithRelatedDataAsync()
        {
            var books = await context.Books
                .AsNoTracking()
                .AsSplitQuery()
                .Include(d => d.Price)
                .Include(d => d.Images)
                .Include(d => d.Author)
                .ToListAsync();

            return books;
        }
```

That is how I use Eager Loading asynchronously. And I've been questioning if when using `Select()`, I was supposed to expect it to be **used** the same way in terms of **asynchronicity**. However I might be completely clouded in that the use of `Select()` is synchronous because it works a different way that I thought it did.

Comment: Why do you want to use `await` in a `Select`? `await` is a .NET thing, whereas `Select` is (usually) used to tell the database what you want. I'm not sure why you are trying to mix them. Maybe if you post some code it would be easier to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: As a general rule, you want to hit the database as few times as possible, and include the data you need in your original query, e.g., using `Include` / eager loading.

Comment: @StephenCleary I see. That's what I've tried to do with `Include()` statements but it seems that in certain circumstances a `Select()` method could do the job better, but it's my first time using it so I was confused as to why it wasn't accepting being async and I'm trying to know why does it makes sense that this method, `Select()`, doesn't need to be async to work as well as `Include()` for the database.

Comment: You should also show your `Select()` version, but also _async_ doesn't give us any better performance from a database point of view, it does however un-block your application, so the application can be more performant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.Select()` or *projections* are generally the most efficient form of data retrieval if [performed on the *server*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval), but when we use *projections* we are precluding the use of includes. `.Select()` will *change the shape* of the object graph, if you are not changing the shape, then just use `.Include()`, [`.AsSplitQuery()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.assplitquery?view=efcore-6.0) gives you the best performance when you need to include related entities because it will load each of the navigation path as an individual query.

- `.Select()` is frequently used in repository patterns to *map* data models into DTOs, there are other libraries you can use that can simplify this that will internally call `.Select()`.
- [As of Core 6, LINQ to Entity Projections also support `.AsSplitQuery()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries?source=recommendations) which means that performance is now less of a concern when choosing between *Eager Loading* and *Projections*.

The point of projecting is to pull back not just the required related navigation entities, but only the specific fields that we need. `.Select()` is therefor an even more *eager* form of loading than `.Include()`, but allows for you to be selective about which fields to load.

But we can't have both `.Select()` *and* `.Include()' in a server expression, in fact any` .Include()`expressed before the`.Select()`will be ignored unless the`.IQueryable()`has been loaded into an`.IEnumerable()` first.

As to *asynchronicity*, there is no difference between `.Select()` or `.Include()` if you apply them to an `IQueryable<T>` expression, the following would still be asynchronous:

```
var books = await context. Books
    .Select(b => new BookDTO {
        ISBN = b.BookNumber,
        Title = b.Title,
        Author = b.Author.Name,
        Price = b.Price,
        Images = b.Images.Select(i => i.Url)
    })
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .ToListAsync();
```

The only time that `.Select()` *might* constrain you to a *synchronous* context is if in your *projection* you have used a function or logic that cannot be converted to a data store (SQL) expression. In this instance EF Core will autmatically evaluate your expression to bring data into memory and *then* it will perform the `.Select()`. At that point you are dealing with `IEnumerable<T>` and *synchronous* evaluations.